# What's the static type of an exception in a multiple exception catch clause?

Tags: java, types

In this code example, what's the static type of `e` in the catch block?

```
try {
    ....
} catch(IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
    //what's the static type of e in here? Is it Exception?
    System.out.println(e.getClass());
}
```

It seems to be effectively `Exception`, but when I hover over it in my IDE it says  `IOException | NumberFormatException`. Is this a special type that only applies to multiple exceptions in catch blocks or does it generalize to other types?

Comment: Yes, the compile-time type is special type  `IOException | NumberFormatException`

Comment: Yeah, just found it too (https://blog.jooq.org/tag/union-types/). Too bad its only for catch blocks, could have been useful elsewhere.

Comment: @Abra That would be the runtime type, not the static (compile-time) type.

Comment: Nice question, but remember: almost *anything* has been asked here before. So please try using a search engine the next time.

Comment: I did try googling for 'static type exception multiple catch java' but the results were cluttered with tutorial articles on how to use multiple exception catch (without going into details about compile time types). I got a good answer though, so all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***TL;DR:** The static type is the nearest common super class.*

---

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html), section [14.20. The `try` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20), says:

> An exception parameter may denote its type as either a single class type or a union of two or more class types (called *alternatives*). The alternatives of a union are syntactically separated by `|`.
>
> A `catch` clause whose exception parameter is denoted as a single class type is called a *uni-`catch` clause*.
>
> A `catch` clause whose exception parameter is denoted as a union of types is called a *multi-`catch` clause*.

> The declared type of an exception parameter that denotes its type with a single class type is that class type.
>
> The declared type of an exception parameter that denotes its type as a union with alternatives D<sub>1</sub> | D<sub>2</sub> | ... | D<sub>n</sub> is lub(D<sub>1</sub>, D<sub>2</sub>, ..., D<sub>n</sub>).

So, it's basically called a "union type", and doesn't exist elsewhere in the language.

---

**UPDATE**

The effective type is the **union of the nearest common super types** (class and/or interfaces), i.e. you can call any method that is common for all the *alternatives*.

The code below illustrates the following points:

- Since both exceptions extend `SuperException`, you can call the `SuperException` method.
- Since both exceptions implement interface `Foo`, you can call the `Foo` method.
- The effective type is not `SuperException`, because then you couldn't call `Foo` methods, and it is not `Foo`, because then you couldn't call `SuperException` methods.
- The effective type is truly a union of the nearest common super types, which really means *all* common super types.

```java
try {
    // some code throwing the exceptions
} catch (SubException1 | SubException2 e) {
    e.methodInSuper();  // you can call the SuperException method
    e.foo();            // you can call the Foo method
}
```

```java
interface Foo {
    void foo();
}
class SuperException extends Exception {
    public void methodInSuper() {
        // code here
    }
}
class SubException1 extends SuperException implements Foo {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        // code here
    }
}
class SubException2 extends SuperException implements Foo {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        // code here
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

To answer the exact question "what's the static type of the exception?", we need to look at the bytecode.

The bytecode of the catch clause of the above code is:

```java
        34: astore_1
        35: aload_1
        36: invokevirtual #33                 // Method SuperException.methodInSuper:()V
        39: aload_1
        40: checkcast     #38                 // class Foo
        43: invokeinterface #40,  1           // InterfaceMethod Foo.foo:()V
        48: return
      Exception table:
         from    to  target type
             0    34    34   Class SubException1
             0    34    34   Class SubException2
```

As you can see, the single `catch` clause registers 2 exceptions to be caught, directing both to the same code block. The call to `SuperException.methodInSuper()` is done straight up. The call to `Foo.foo()` is done after casting to `Foo`. The compiled code can be consider equivalent to the follow, except it only catches the 2 subexceptions:

```java
} catch (SuperException e) { // only catch SubException1 and SubException2
    e.methodInSuper();
    ((Foo) e).foo();
}
```

***Conclusion:*** The static type is the **nearest common super class**. Any additional common interfaces that is not defined by that super class are silently be handled by the compiler using casts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Weird decision for Java to not have union types everywhere else though.